# Order status indicator color

Tags: android, icons, color, status, indicator

I am creating an android app from which user can order goods. I am using an price tag with various colors to indicate the order status.

The statuses are

- OPEN - Immediate status after ordering, open order
- ACKNOWLEDGED - Seller has acknowledged and updated the price
- CONFIRMED - User has confirmed the order after seeing the price
- CANCELED - User has cancelled the order
- CLOSED - Order/delivery completed

Here is screenshot of the app [image: Order list]

The price tag indicates the status.

Is this a good indicator ? And what should be the colors of the statuses ?

Also how should I indicate user action needed for ACKNOWLEDGED status ?

---

Edit: Here is the new gui. What do you think ?

[image: new gui with animation]

Comment: Why only use colour? What about for colour-blind people? Or for users who need a screen reader?

Answer (score 4):

As a user, I would have no idea what the different colors would mean. I think you should write the title of each status underneath in small caps. If you do that, here are my color suggestions:

- OPEN - Blue, by default color.
- ACKNOWLEDGED - Orange, you need to notify the user. You could have the button fade rapidly from grey to white and back to show that the user's attention is required.
- CONFIRMED - Green, generally the color used for "Ok"
- CANCELED - Red, as it is generally associated with that kind of warning/message
- CLOSED - Light grey, to show it's inactive.

Comment: I agree with you. The user wouldn't have any idea about the meaning of colors. I will add status to the list. Thank you for the color suggestions. Also I am animating the tag like a swing to show it needs user attention.

Comment: I would also use a different icon for each status

Comment: why those colours?

Comment: The colors seem random to me, some kind of decoration. Some websites use descriptive icons like a transit van, or creditcard.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, though it depends on the details of application and the purchase process, but I believe that those are too much status.

"open order" is the default status of any order, because there is no "closed order" before purchase. default status does not need an extra indicator.

For "acknowledged" , it will make sense only if the order is from a third party supplier. If it is an online store, then the store is always aware about any order in progress , This includes the price thing. If it is online store, then the price is fixed, and the user HAVE TO KNOW the price beforehand.

For "Cancelled" , it will make sense only if you want the user to be able to keep track of his abandoned orders, which is fairly uncommon.

And you may have one missing status : name it "Failed" for example, to indicate the failure of delivering the order to its destination, specially for long orders.

For the indicator in figure, I think the user may skip it. You need a more eye catching indicator, and do not depend on the color alone. Use an icon other than the price tag, because the user may miss interpret it for price meaning. You can color the whole form if you like.

Best regards.

Comment: The user will have no idea about the price beforehand, hence the "acknowledged" status.  I will merge the cancelled and failed status. For user interaction indicator, I am animating the tag. I will post an another screenshot shortly.